# Adding an Authorization token to an ExoPlayer's request

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

I want to stream videos using ExoPlayer from my server which uses token authentication to validate if a user is permitted to read the file (Django), and to do this I have to include an Authentication Token in the header of a request, like this

```
 Authorization Token d4637461d8d7ea159884264beef618b6a6e90485
```

The ExoPlayer documentation from https://exoplayer.dev/customization.html says I must do it like this

```
 DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = () -> {
     HttpDataSource dataSource = httpDataSourceFactory.createDataSource();
     // Set a custom authentication request header.
     dataSource.setRequestProperty("Header", "Value");
     return dataSource;
 };
```

Which I then set to my player like this

```
 SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context)
      .setMediaSourceFactory(new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory))
      .build();
```

But Android Studio says it cannot resolve symbol `httpDataSourceFactory`. So I scrolled up to find any variable named `httpDataSourceFactory`, which I found as

```
 // Build a HttpDataSource.Factory with cross-protocol redirects enabled.
 HttpDataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory =
      new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true);
```

But now I am getting the error

> Reference to 'Factory' is ambiguous, both 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource.Factory' and 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource.Factory' match

[image: Error 2]

Could it be I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies I was using from the the documentation were

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.12.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.12.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.12.0'
```

The errors resolved the moment I upgraded my dependencies to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.14.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.14.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.14.1'
```